# Does physicalism think a priori knowledge exists?

Tags: epistemology, physicalism

Does physicalism think a priori knowledge exists? If so, how is this knowledge explained? Is the idea like morality being coded in DNA?

Comment: what does "prior" mean? Do you mean *a priori* (which would make better sense but still not be easy to follow).

Comment: @virmaior Kant argues morality must exist in something priori something pure. But If I hold the view that human merely consists of cells in terms of biology. How can I resolve these two ideas?